# javascript setting style to first element only

Tags: javascript, dom

i have this simple HTML with some javascript on table element. I have two buttons as Even and Odd. When even button clicked i want element belongs to class Even should have yellow background. and similarly when odd button clicked, rows with class Odd should turns to yellow. Below is the code i have written but on clicking a button it is changing color of one row only. could anybody please advise. may be i can count number of rows and then go with a for loop but what is wrong in below code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Even & Odd row event</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tab">
    <thead>
        <tr class="hdr">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Module</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>HANA UI5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>PI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>CDS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>DDD</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>FIORI UI5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
<button id="btn1">Even</button>
<button id="btn2">Odd</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="dom7.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
var btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");


btn1.onclick = function(){
    var c1 = document.querySelector(".odd");
    c1.style.backgroundColor = "whit`enter code here`e";
    var c2 = document.querySelector(".even");
    //debugger;
    c2.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

btn2.onclick = function(){
    var c3 = document.querySelector(".odd");
    c3.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    var c4 = document.querySelector(".even");
    c4.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Comment: You have some mistakes in your code from copying into the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Document#querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns a single node. Use [Document#querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead, because it returns a collection of nodes. Then iterate the nodes using `.forEach()` to assign the background color.

Note: Document#querySelectorAll returns an `elementList` (a subclass of `nodeList`), and not an array. The [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) support of `forEach` is limited. If the `forEach` doesn't work for you, convert the `nodeList` to an array - see the comments for the `odd` and `even` variables.

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
var btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn2");
var odd = document.querySelectorAll(".odd"); // [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".odd"), 0);
var even = document.querySelectorAll(".even"); // [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".even"), 0)

function updateRowColors(color_odd, color_even) {
  odd.forEach(function updateColor(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = color_odd;
  });
  
  even.forEach(function updateColor(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = color_even;
  });
}

btn1.onclick = function(){
  updateRowColors('white', 'yellow');
}

btn2.onclick = function(){
  updateRowColors('yellow', 'white');
}
```

```html
<table id="tab">
    <thead>
        <tr class="hdr">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Module</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>HANA UI5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>BBB</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>PI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>CCC</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>CDS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>DDD</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>FIORI UI5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
<button id="btn1">Even</button>
<button id="btn2">Odd</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

from w3schools:

The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document. Note: The querySelector() method only returns the first element that matches the specified selectors. To return all the matches, use the querySelectorAll() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a selector like or you add the property to the css class:

```
document.querySelector('.even').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

The querySelector returns the first element matching the query.